# How can I get the partial data downloaded by cURL?

Tags: curl, timeout

I am using curl on PHP to grab some pages.  I set the timeout at 10 seconds.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
```

I often get a response of:

> Operation timed out after 10015 milliseconds with 447539 bytes received

The standard `$result=curl_exec($ch)` returns false on the error, returning only the whole page if there is no error.

I only need the first parts of the pages being captured.  How can I store and get the data downloaded so far?